# Process a duplicate list into an unique list

Tags: javascript

I have a countries array and a provider array which has duplicate providers concatenated by countries.

What i am looking for is an array looks like expectation where code should be provider name and countries should be a list like and this has to be unique.

```
countryList = ['CL','BR','CO','MX','US']
providers =  ['MERCADOLIBRE_CL','MERCADOLIBRE_BR','MERCADOLIBRE_CO','MERCADOLIBRE_MX','VERIZON','VERIZON','DGMI_UK']
expectation = [
    {code: "MERCADOLIBRE", countries: :['CL','MX','BR','CO']},
    {code: "DGMI_UK", countries: []},
    {code: "VERIZON", countries: []},
]
```

I am able to generate the below list with the code mentioned:

```
[MERCADOLIBRE,DGMI_UK,VERIZON]

providers.forEach((str) => {
                var rest = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("_"));
                var last = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("_") + 1, str.length);
                var found = countryList.includes(last)
                var provider = (found) ? rest : str
                if(list.includes(provider) === false) list.push(provider);
            })
```

Comment: `var found = countryList.find(elem => elem.code === last)` - that makes little sense; your `countryList` does not contain any _objects_ that could have a `code` property, it contains plain strings.

Comment: countryList is an array having countries in it , providers is an array having duplicate providers with country concatinated at the end. What i am looking for is an array looks like expectation where code should be provider name and countries should be a list like and this has to be unique.

Comment: I am able to generate a list which has unique proivders without country code 

[MERCADOLIBRE,DGMI_UK,VERIZON]

the  code var found = countryList.find(elem => elem.code === last) , is checking if country code i received from providers name exists in the list or not , if it doesn't exists then provider name will be e.g. DGMI_UK else MERCADOLIBRE instead of MERCADOLIBRE_CL

Comment: _"is checking if country code i received from providers name exists in the list or not"_ - no, it is _not_ doing that. `elem` is a _string_ value ('CL', 'BR', etc.) - and those string values do not _have_ any `code` property. `elem.code` is _undefined_ in your callback function, and therefor `=== last` will never be true.

Comment: You need to check if your `expectation` array (which appears to be `list` in the shown code snippet) already contains a matching element. If not, you need to add a new element; otherwise, you need to add the `last` value to the `countries` array of the found item.

Comment: ahh appologies the countryList array was multidimensional i have changed that to look like eg above. i have updated the code i am using

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77765082/javascript-arrays-processing?

Comment: I have deleted the old question and created this new one @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
const countryList = ['CL','BR','CO','MX','US'];
const providers = ['MERCADOLIBRE_CL','MERCADOLIBRE_BR','MERCADOLIBRE_CO','MERCADOLIBRE_MX','VERIZON','VERIZON','DGMI_UK'];

// Group providers by code
const grouped = providers.reduce((acc, provider) => {
  const parts = provider.split('_');
  const code = parts[0];
  const country = parts[1];

  if (!acc[code]) {
    acc[code] = {code, countries: []}; 
  }

  if (country && countryList.includes(country)) {
    acc[code].countries.push(country);
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

// Convert to array
const result = Object.values(grouped);

console.log(result);
```

[image: Output]

The key steps:

1. Split each provider on '_' to separate code and country
2. Group into object by code
3. Build up countries array for each code
4. Convert object to array